# How can I see traffic from shared Wifi (Macbook AirPort)?

Tags: wifi, internet-sharing

I want to see a log. 
 Something like: `192.168.0.23 www.example.url 13:34 19 april 2011`

Comment: You could try checking out similar questions in superuser.com since this has nothing specifically to do with Mac since there are many OpenSource tools for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is a command-line utility to see the traffic on any network interface.  It is full-featured, but can require some serious reading of the man page.

Wireshark is a full-featured application that will allow you to see all such traffic.  It provides a GUI (X-windows based) into which you can specify filters on traffic and collect statistics.  See more info and download it at [wireshark.org](http://wireshark.org).  I find knowledge of Wireshark to be very, very helpful with lots of network tasks.

Comment: I added a link for tcpdump. I hope it's the right software. Forgive me if it's not!

Comment: No problem.  Improving the answers is what it's all about.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

[Debookee](http://www.iwaxx.com/debookee) will do the job for the following protocols: HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, TCP, DHCP, SIP ...

There's also a scanner included that can show you all the devices on your network.

But the best to me is the interceptor tool that allows you to see the traffic of any device (mobile, tablet, other Mac or PC) on your network, like Cain & Abel for Windows.

Comment: Please read http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion before promoting your own product.